# Geometric interpretation of ln(c) = ln(xy)= ln(x)+ln(y)

Tags: real-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

For $c,x,y>0$, and $c$ a constant, factoring $c$ into a product can be interpreted as taking a square of area $c$ and morphing it into a rectangle with sides of length $x$ and $y$ with equal area.

Is there a similarly transparent direct geometric interpretation of $\ln(c)=\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ perhaps in hyperbolic geometry?

---

It's really quite an amazing invariance when looking at the infinite series

$$ \ln(x) = \ln[1-(1-x)] = -\sum_{k>0}\frac{(1-x)^k}{k}.$$

Then, e.g., with $x=y=1/2$,

$$\ln(1/4) = \ln(1/2) + \ln(1/2)$$

implies

$$ \sum_{k>0}\frac{(3/4)^k}{k} =   \sum_{k>0}\frac{2(1/2)^k}{k}. $$

No way. Yet ... .

Comment: Wikipedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Log.gif

Comment: The gif and answer are very nice. Since distances between points in Poincare's disc model of hyperbolic geometry are measured as the log of ratios, there might also be an interpretation in terms of that model too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided the log is defined via 
$$\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac1t\,dt,$$
we first have for positive number $c$:
$$\int_1^x\frac1t\,dt=\int_{c}^{cx}\frac1t\,dt.$$
Felix Klein once gave this explanation:

> This means that the area between the ordinates $1$ 
>   and $x$ is the same as that between the ordinates $c$ and $cx$ which are $c$ times as far from the origin.  We can make this clear geometrically by observing that *the area remains the same when we slide it along the $x$-axis under the curve provided we stretch the width in the same ratio as we shrink the height.*  From this the addition theorem follows at once:
>   $$\begin{align}
> \int_1^x\frac1t\,dt+\int_1^y\frac1t\,dt&=
> \int_1^x\frac1t\,dt+\int_x^{xy}\frac1t\,dt\\
> &=
> \int_1^{xy}\frac1t\,dt.
> \end{align}$$

Elementary Mathematics from an advanced standpoint, p.156