# Why $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln{x}$?

Tags: integration

*I used the search, but for some reason I can not find such a question. This is probably very simple, but not for me...*

I want to understand why $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln{x} +\rm  const$?

I'm trying to solve this as $$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \int x^{-1} dx = \int x^{-1} dx = \frac{x^{-1+1}}{-1+1} + {\rm const}=\frac{x^0}{0} + \rm const=\frac{1}{0} + const$$

How do I uncover uncertainty?

I don't know how to apply knowledge about the logarithm ($x=\log_{a} b \Leftrightarrow a^x=b$) in this case.

Comment: It follows from the [inverse function theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) and $\exp'(x)=\exp(x)$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem?

Comment: The reason is simply because $(\ln x)’=1/x$. The answer by @WW1 shows why that is true, if you don’t already know it.

Comment: We just *define* $\ln(x)=\int_1^t\frac{dt}{t}$.  Then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390834/geometric-interpretation-of-lnc-lnxy-lnxlny/3390902#3390902, please.

Answer (score 8):

It may help to think about definite integrals viz.$$\epsilon\ne0,\,x>0\implies\int_1^xt^{\epsilon-1}dt=\frac{x^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon},$$so$$x>0\implies\int_1^xt^{-1}dt=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{x^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}=\ln x\cdot\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{e^{\epsilon\ln x}-1}{\epsilon\ln x}.$$But this last limit is the definition of the $y$-derivative of $e^y$ at $0$, since $h:=\epsilon\ln x\to0$ as $\epsilon\to0$. This limit is $1$, completing the proof.

Comment: Very kind user for my humble opinion $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln{|x|}+k, \, k\in \Bbb R$. My upvoted.

Comment: @Sebastiano As I said, I was only checking the case $x>0$. Incidentally, $k$ need only be *locally constant* in the indefinite integral, i.e. it can have a different value for $x<0$.

Comment: I misspelled :-( I was referring to the user who did not put the absolute value and the constant.

Comment: @Sebastiano I missed **+ const** :(

Comment: @Andrew Upvoted also your question :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks. The problem is that I can't understand the answers *J.G.* and *Ian*. I don't have enough knowledge.

Comment: @Andrew If you know the power rule for powers other than $-1$, definite integrals, and you know how to differentiate $a^x$ with respect to $x$, then you can read my answer. The subtle thing about all of this is that there are a whole bunch of interrelated facts about exponentials and logarithms, but some subset of those facts have to be taken as *definitions* rather than facts.

Comment: @Ian At school we are told to use a lists of integrals. But I can’t do this, I need to understand what it really is.

Comment: @J.G. Let me come back to this question later and read this answer again.

Answer (score 4):

So the power rule breaks down because of a division by zero, however there is still continuity as you move the exponent through $-1$, provided that you are considering a definite integral, or at least an integral with one limit of integration pinned down. Conventionally we do this by pinning the lower limit to $1$ and allowing the upper limit to vary. Thus you look at $\int_1^x y^p dy = \frac{x^{p+1}-1}{p+1}$, with $x>0$.

Now you send $p \to -1$, which amounts to computing $\frac{d}{dp} x^{p+1}$ at $p=-1$. Now the connection to the exponential comes from the need to differentiate an exponential expression with respect to its exponent.

There is no continuity in the usual statement of the power rule for indefinite integrals, i.e. $\int x^p dx = \frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}$, because this corresponds to $\int_0^x y^p dy$ which is not a finite integral when $p \leq -1$.

Comment: I read your answer, but I do not have enough knowledge to understand it.

Comment: Let me come back to this question later and read this answer again.

Answer (score 4):

for $x>0$ we have ...
$$ e^{\ln x} = x \implies \frac{d}{dx}  e^{\ln x} = 1 $$

Calculate the same derivative using chain rule ...

$$ \frac{d}{dx}  e^{\ln x} = e^{\ln x}  \bigg (  \frac{d}{dx}  \ln x \bigg )
\\ = x \bigg ( \frac{d}{dx}  \ln x \bigg ) $$

Equating the two expressions you get

$$   \frac{d}{dx}  \ln x  =\frac 1x$$

The result now follows from the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: This is the best answer. The real answer is just “because $(\ln x)’=1/x$”, and this show why that’s true.